# RandomForest( ) more than 32factor levels

Tags: r, categorical-data, random-forest, binning, many-categories

I used randomForest( ) function in R. But R can't deal variables that more 32factor levels. But my factor variables are very important thing. So I want to use this variable. Then, how to deal this variable?

I know why randomForest( ) can't handle factor variable that have more 32 levels. But I'm wondering that how to use this categorical variable.

Binning the categorical variable??? or just delete?? ??

Comment: Here is a similar question:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270201/pooling-levels-of-categorical-variables-for-regression-trees/275867#275867

Answer (score 2):

You can either try what Sainath said, or you can do one hot encoding of your variable, which will make a different column for each of your factor levels and the values in those columns would be 0 or 1 depending on whether that row contained that factor level. You can read how to do it [here](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2017/04/encoding-categorical-variables-one-hot-and-beyond/).
I personally suggest doing one hot encoding of every factor variable regardless of whether it has more than 32 levels or not.

Comment: +1 This is what is called [dummy variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)) in standard regression terminology.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to combine the levels with low frequency into a single level. This will reduce the total number of levels, and may even bring it to <32 levels.

Another way would be to calculate the frequency of each level in the variable, and use this as a feature.

Yet another way is the Impact coding approach. For more details regarding the Impact coding technique, see this article http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2012/07/modeling-trick-impact-coding-of-categorical-variables-with-many-levels/.